# Botpress timeout flow javascript code does not seem to be working

Tags: javascript, botpress

I want to set a timer for one minute, during the timer keep checking the workflow.stillThere variable every second, if it is not empty, stop the code execution

```
const timerDuration = luxon.Duration.fromObject({ minutes: 1 });
const endTime = luxon.DateTime.local().plus(timerDuration);

const checkStillThere = async () => {
  while (luxon.DateTime.local() < endTime) {
    if (workflow.stillThere) {
      break;
    }
    await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000));
  }
};

await checkStillThere();
```

It does not seem to be working, could someone please direct me in the right direction?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: that is all the ode I have, I am trying to execute it on botpress